# add and remove class when toggling through radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove a class based on a radio button behavior. The idea is if the selected radio button value is paypal then all the class="required" form input fields gets removed and when toggled to credit card all the fields which got the class required removed from them gets the required class back. Here is how I am doing it

```
$('input[name*="payment"]').on('change', function() {
  var type = this.value;
  switch (type) {
    case 'paypal':
      $('#payment input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
          $(this).removeClass('required');
          $(this).addClass('requiredFalse');
        }
      });
    case 'creditcard':
      $('#payment input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('requiredFalse')) {
          $(this).addClass('required');
          $(this).removeClass('requiredFalse');
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle. Cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/d225cdrp/1/

Comment: try my answer to make your code bit shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [switch-case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is missing the breaks. So when type was "paypal" both cases were executed, this is how switch works. So try this:

```
$('input[name*="payment"]').on('change', function() {
  var type = this.value;
  switch (type) {
    case 'paypal':
      $('#payment input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
          $(this).removeClass('required');
          $(this).addClass('requiredFalse');
        }
      });
      break;
    case 'creditcard':
      $('#payment input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('requiredFalse')) {
          $(this).addClass('required');
          $(this).removeClass('requiredFalse');
        }
      });
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats all it was hah...cant believe I missed that. Now I am embarrassed. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name*="payment"]').on('change', function() {
  var type = this.value;
  switch (type) {
    case 'paypal':
      $('#payment input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
          $(this).removeClass('required');
          $(this).addClass('requiredFalse');
        }
      });
      break;
    case 'creditcard':
      $('#payment input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('requiredFalse')) {
          $(this).addClass('required');
          $(this).removeClass('requiredFalse');
        }
      });
      break;
  }
  //console.log(type);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try toggleClass to make your code more shorter.

```
//To remove require and add requiredFalse 
$(this).toggleClass("required requiredFalse");

//To add requireFalse and remove require
$(this).toggleClass("requiredFalse required");
```

More info about toggleClass can be found here. 
[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

**Snippet to check the working example**

```js
$('input[name*="payment"]').on('change', function() {
  var type = this.value;
  switch (type) {
    case 'paypal':
          $('#payment input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {
              $(this).toggleClass("required requiredFalse");
            }
          });
          break;
    case 'creditcard':
          $('#payment input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('requiredFalse')) {
              $(this).toggleClass("requiredFalse required");
            }
          });
          break;
    }
})
```

```css
.requiredFalse {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.required {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>creditcard</div>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="creditcard">
<div>paypal</div>
<input type="radio" name="payment" value="paypal">
<form id="payment">
  <input class="required" type="text" id="address1">
  <input type="text" id="address2">
  <input class="required" type="text" id="zipcode">
</form>
```

Comment: This is great. But I think toggleClass() has some issues in IE8 :-(

Comment: @soum now a days, most of the people are using latest browsers only.

Comment: Great, reward the answers which helps you in your question.